# Why gnuplot don't work. Bad cpu type in executable

Tags: macos, gnuplot, zsh, cpu, macos-catalina

I've installed gnuplot with Homebrew, but when i launch the gnuplot command on terminal it says: "zsh: bad CPU type in executable: gnuplot". I have Mac Os Catalina 10.15.4. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find out what you are actually running when you run `gnuplot`:

```
type gnuplot
gnuplot is /SOMETHING/SOMEWHERE
```

Now you know what you are actually running. Note the result. Now find what type of file that is:

```
file /SOMETHING/SOMEWHERE
```

You are hoping that results in `Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64` which would be correct for an Intel Mac, unless you are on Apple Silicon.